# How to set up Rxdb with pouchdb-adapter-leveldb?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, electron, pouchdb

I am working on electron app and I am using react,react-redux. Now I am trying to set up Rxdb and pouchdb-adapter-leveldb for offline mode, I took Rxdb(react) - example and made little changes for pouchdb-adapter-leveldb. this is my database.js file:

```
import * as RxDB from 'rxdb';

var PouchDB = require('pouchdb-core')
    .plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-leveldb'));
RxDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-leveldb'));

const collections = [
    {
        name: 'heroes',
        schema: require('./Schema.js').default,
        methods: {
            hpPercent() {
                return this.hp / this.maxHP * 100;
            }
        },
        sync: true
    }
];

const syncURL = 'http://localhost:3000/teams';
console.log('host: ' + syncURL);
// const syncURL = host;

let dbPromise = null;

const _create = async function() {


    console.log('DatabaseService: creating database..');

    const db = await RxDB.create({name: 'heroesreactdb', adapter: 'leveldb', password: 'myLongAndStupidPassword'});
    console.log('DatabaseService: created database');
    window['db'] = db; // write to window for debugging

    // show leadership in title
    db.waitForLeadership().then(() => {
        console.log('isLeader now');
        document.title = '♛ ' + document.title;
    });

    // create collections
    console.log('DatabaseService: create collections');
    await Promise.all(collections.map(colData => db.collection(colData)));

    // hooks
    console.log('DatabaseService: add hooks');
    db.collections.heroes.preInsert(function(docObj) {
        const color = docObj.color;
        return db.collections.heroes.findOne({color}).exec().then(has => {
            if (has != null) {
                alert('another hero already has the color ' + color);
                throw new Error('color already there');
            }
            return db;
        });
    });

    // sync
    console.log('DatabaseService: sync');
    collections.filter(col => col.sync).map(col => col.name).map(colName => db[colName].sync({
        remote: syncURL + colName + '/'
    }));

    return db;
};

export function get() {
    if (!dbPromise)
        dbPromise = _create();
    return dbPromise;
}
```

[![and this is my error notification:
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhYb8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhYb8.png)

when I saw this error message, I delete nod-modules, and install node-bindings (One guy suggested this solution) but it did't work for me. Any idea how to fix this :? :/ thanks!!!

Comment: It seems that you are attempting to run leveldb in the browser? Afaik leveldb only works with node. Maybe you can try to modify [the official node example](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/tree/master/examples/node) to run leveldb, and check if it works?

Comment: Thanck you very much to trying to help me, after one month finally someone comment on my question, I appraciate that! thanks. I've already fixed this problem and forgot to write answer. I added "webpack-node-externals" in my webpack file and only RxDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-leveldb')); this line was enough to add in my Database file. Thanks one more time !